# FileReader to read from bottom to top or stringbuffer?

Tags: android, filereader, stringbuffer

this file saves (date,time, voice input newline()) im wondering how to process this file into the textview so it reads it from the bottom to the top so i can put the most recent at the top of the textview, thankyou for your time

```
 wi =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hes);
        try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/data/jip.lam.ru/file"));
            String inputString;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
            while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
            }
            wi.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: do the string reversal and put the recent in textview

Comment: is there a method or something for string reversal?

Comment: StringBuffer.reverse(); im trying it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a Stack.

```
 String inputString;
    Stack<String> readbuffer =new Stack<String>();
     while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) 
     {
       readbuffer.push(inputString);
     }
```

Now pop the Stack i.e 
wi.setText(readbuffer.pop());

Comment: hey thanks i never heard of that ill remember for next time, i used 2 strings and just flipped the textview around

Comment: Stacks are like a pile of books,they follow the LIFO(LAST IN FIRST OUT order) i.e Suppose you have a stack of Books i.e A1,A2,A3,A4 and you insert push them in the same order then when you pop it,the first element to come out is A4,A3,A2 and then A1 i.e reverse way.. this will help you in reading the filebackwards..